# How to let users create lists of woocommerce products?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, list, bookmark

I've almost finished my website https://laforetcomestible.org/ It's a french database of plants to create of forest garden (free and collaborative) built with wordpress and woocommerce.

**I'd like to give users the ability to create lists of plants.**

> ie: bookmark 5 plants in a list called 'my forest 1' and bookmark 10
>   plants in another list called 'my forest 2' displayed like this
>   (which is the shop layout).[image]

These are the **functions I am looking for**:

- **Add / Delete** plants lists
- **Name** plants lists
- **Add / Delete** plants in plants lists
- **Show** lists on a member page/profile

My knowledge is a bit limited but I am here to learn. **Could you please advise what would be the simplest way to add this feature ?**

Thanks a lot,
daam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already using woocommerce to showcase your plants , you can use woocommerce wishlists https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-wishlists/ to create lists , most of the features are built in but you may need to manage the way it shows in front-end. I am pretty confident you can pull this by the way you got this stunning site ready.

Let me know how it goes,
Naveen.